How to configure/rewrite an inbound URL/endpoint of a Web API hosted on IIS to redirect to a different URL
I hosted a Web API on IIS on one of our test servers which will be listening at https://mytestserver.com/Test/Api/Status but the client will actually send PUT request to https://mytestserver.com/api/credential/PostFinalize/Test/Status which needs to be redirected to https://mytestserver.com/Test/Api/Status.
I tried URL Rewrite editor in IIS Manager with no success. Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
